# How to get tuple of two lists from dictionary with dictionary keys sorted?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, ienumerable

I have `Dictionary<DateTime, double> dict;` and I want to create `Tuple<List<DateTime>, List<double>> result;`

Condition: The resulting `result.Item1` of the resulting tuple has to be sorted in ascending order and, `dict[result.Item1[n]] == result.Item2[n]` for each index n.

Thanks

Comment: did the downvotes make you think that this question need more explanation?

Comment: Why do you have to do that?

Comment: Why all the downvotes? At least explain why the question does not make sense, but just downvoting is lame.

Comment: ascending order of what ? dates ?

Comment: Ascending order of items in Item1 collection of the resulting tuple, meaning ascending order of `DateTime` per definition I stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
var kvList = dict.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key).ToList();
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>(kvList.Count);
dates.AddRange(kvList.Select(kv => kv.Key));
List<double> doubles = new List<double>(kvList.Count);
doubles.AddRange(kvList.Select(kv => kv.Value));
var result = Tuple.Create(dates, doubles);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that should work:

```
List<DateTime> dateTimes = dict.Keys.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
Tuple<List<DateTime>, List<double>> result = new Tuple<List<DateTime>, List<double>>(dateTimes, dateTimes.Select(x=>dict[x]).ToList());
```